# Android Studio is generating old version of signed apk

Tags: java, android, xml

Whenever I build an APK it behaves badly, if I click generate bundle it takes my old res files (which was replaced),then when I generate a normal V1 and V2 APK it builds with the old AndroidManifest.xml

I tried invalidate cache, rebuild, clean

### Expected configuration

[image: Expected configuration]

### Generated Configuration

[image: The generated]
[image: Generated AndroidManifest.xml]

Comment: I thought that all the version info now goes in build gradle...not sure thats an answer but that is where it is for me.  The App level build gradle file.

Comment: I think you need to change versionCode and versionName in build.gradle. Have you done it?

Comment: @NameSurname Yes, doesn't work. I'm looking into the app build.gradle defaultconfigs, do you know if that affects in apk packing?

Comment: If you done Rebuild, Clear, Invalidate - So watch this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYwym0EzDLE